# How to draw or implement a pie chart using phpspreadsheet?

Tags: phpspreadsheet

Well, I did not found any documentation for the graph chart except the API documentation which is cryptic for me, so if any of the PHPspreadsheet saw this please consider document this class.
My question is how to draw a pie chart and implement it into an excel sheet, view it directly or save it to a file or all the previous if possible

Comment: I'm not sure, if PhpSpreadsheet can create graphs inside a spreadsheet.

Try to create a template Spreadsheet, which contains the graph already, and just modify it with PhpSpreadsheet, thats how we done it.

Comment: @MirkoSteiner It can, as could its predecessor PHPExcel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at the examples at all? In `Samples/Charts`, the [33_Chart_create_pie.php](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/master/samples/Chart/33_Chart_create_pie.php) example is fairly clear, showing how to create a pie chart, with plenty of comments explaining what each line of code is doing

Comment: Thank you for hinting me that. I did not even knew it exists before I asked my question. I will look into it and come back if I did not get it from the example above.

Comment: Yes Sir, you answered my question the above example and the collection of examples around it gives me what I was looking for, thank you